# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Tags: selenium-webdriver

public static void month(WebDriver driver)

```
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Onward Date']")).click();
    while(!driver.findElement(By.className("monthTitle")).getText().contains("May"))
    {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[class='next'] button")).click();
    }
}
```

[image: CHeck the below attached image below, Have accessed the > next button through CSS selector]

Please help me on this

Comment: The error is self explanatory - `The element cannot be interacted upon`. By the time you're clicking on the button, it is disabled and cannot be clicked. See if adding a couple of seconds waiting helps.

Comment: Questions of this nature are here almost every day. Have you searched the forum? What have you found? In general, you should learn about waits and read https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/41860/41012