# unable to select a value from drop down

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

[image]I am unable to select a value from drop down while automating UI of a website

```java
public void setTargetPortalDropdownOptionInModalPopUp(String visibleText)
{
        Select select = new Select(targetPortalDropDownInModalPopUp);
        select.selectByIndx(9);
}
```

Comment: Which is your element locator , please put the dom also. And remember that select works only with select tag.

Comment: Related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium

Comment: where is HTML for select element?