# Object is not recognizing through webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
List val=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui basic button floating item dropdown']//div//a"));
```

is not identifying through webdriver. But this xpath perfectly recognizing at chrome browser.

Comment: What error are you getting? Could you add how the DOM looks like? How do you wait for the element? Maybe this link helps: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Please verify it within the chrome console with the following command:

```
$x("yourxpat")
```

This will show you how many elements are you getting, i know some friends uses the find by option instead of the console and they only show one by one and if it finds multiple it will fail.