# Selenium vba XPath/css Element not found for

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome, vbscript

I need help!

I'm trying to connect to this Webpage and interact with it via WebDriver. I managed to open the page but when I'm trying to interact I get this error. I tried to press this Link/Button which has the `class "afpaas-quick-link ng-scope afpaas-condition-mobile-display"`

and this was my code:

```
b = "afpaas-quick-link ng-scope afpaas-condition-mobile-display"
'obj.FindElementByClass(b).Click
```

Here I get the error "compound class names not permitted" so I checked google and the answer was Xpath/Css

I was able to get the CSS/Xpath via Chrome Inspector. Here are the two paths

```
body > div > div.afpaas-body > div > div.afpaas-sidebar.afpaas-sidebar--hide > div.afpaas-quick-links-container > div > a:nth-child(2)
'/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/a[2]
```

I tried both but I get the error No Such Element found.... Why? What am I doing wrong?

The code I tried is

```
obj.FindElementByCss("body > div > div.afpaas-body > div > div.afpaas-sidebar.afpaas-sidebar--hide > div.afpaas-quick-links-container > div > a:nth-child(2)").Click

obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/a[2]").Click
```

Here is more of the page code

Schnellzugriff
                
                    
                        
                        Neue Überweisung

```
            </a>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks -->
            <a ng-repeat-start="quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks" ng-repeat-end="" href="/afp/de/group/quirinbank/mypaas-quick-links/_ql_my-wealth/ql_new-trading-order" class="mypaas-quick-link ng-scope mypaas-condition-mobile-display" ng-class="{'mypaas-condition-mobile-display': isMenuItemConditionMobile(quickLink)}" ng-click="quickLinkClicked(quickLink, $event)">
                <i class="mypaas-icon mypaas-icon-neworder"/>
                <span ng-bind="quickLink.label" class="ng-binding">Neue Order</span>
            </a>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks -->
            <a ng-repeat-start="quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks" ng-repeat-end="" href="/afp/de/group/quirinbank/mypaas-quick-links/_ql_my-wealth/_ql_payment-overview" class="mypaas-quick-link ng-scope" ng-class="{'mypaas-condition-mobile-display': isMenuItemConditionMobile(quickLink)}" ng-click="quickLinkClicked(quickLink, $event)">
                <i class="mypaas-icon mypaas-icon-paymentoverview"/>
                <span ng-bind="quickLink.label" class="ng-binding">Zahlungsübersicht</span>
            </a>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks -->
            <a ng-repeat-start="quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks" ng-repeat-end="" href="/afp/de/group/quirinbank/mypaas-quick-links/_ql_my-wealth/_ql_trading-order-overview" class="mypaas-quick-link ng-scope" ng-class="{'mypaas-condition-mobile-display': isMenuItemConditionMobile(quickLink)}" ng-click="quickLinkClicked(quickLink, $event)">
                <i class="mypaas-icon mypaas-icon-orders"/>
                <span ng-bind="quickLink.label" class="ng-binding">Orderübersicht</span>
            </a>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks -->
            <a ng-repeat-start="quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks" ng-repeat-end="" href="/afp/de/group/quirinbank/mypaas-quick-links/_ql_my-wealth/_ql_account-statement" class="mypaas-quick-link ng-scope" ng-class="{'mypaas-condition-mobile-display': isMenuItemConditionMobile(quickLink)}" ng-click="quickLinkClicked(quickLink, $event)">
                <i class="mypaas-icon mypaas-icon-transactions"/>
                <span ng-bind="quickLink.label" class="ng-binding">Kontoumsätze</span>
            </a>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks -->
            <a ng-repeat-start="quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks" ng-repeat-end="" href="/afp/de/group/quirinbank/mypaas-quick-links/_ql_my-wealth/_ql_new-report" class="mypaas-quick-link ng-scope mypaas-condition-mobile-display" ng-class="{'mypaas-condition-mobile-display': isMenuItemConditionMobile(quickLink)}" ng-click="quickLinkClicked(quickLink, $event)">
                <i class="mypaas-icon mypaas-icon-documents"/>
                <span ng-bind="quickLink.label" class="ng-binding">Berichte anfordern</span>
            </a>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: quickLink in quickLinkItem.quickLinks -->
```

[image]

Comment: please provide the website link and the lin ky ou want to click  , try using explicit wait

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to analyse 'Element not Found' exceptions when working with Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium)

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
obj.FindElementByCss('[class="afpaas-quick-link ng-scope afpaas-condition-mobile-display"]')
```

Also check iframe, waits etc as mentioned in the link in comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
//a[contains(@href,"q1_new-trading-order")]
```

Comment: Hey thx for the replay... but i still get the Runtime error '7' NoSuchElementError

obj.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(@href,'q1_new-trading-order')]").Click

Comment: Can you send the source of the page, the image only shows the element and not the whole structure, it would be helpful to identify if element is enclosed in an iframe, and also, waiting for the element to be visible should be a way to avoid this error, probably your code tries to click on that element even before it is available in the dom.