# Can't locate element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

[image]

I am trying to click on the link shown on the attachment but, no matter what I try, webdriver can't find the element. I tried these:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a").click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='P0005 - ORP TEST Dev Team 4 Mateusz']").click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("P0005 - ORP TEST Dev Team 4 Mateusz").click()
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Do you wait for the element/page to load? Your selectors look ok.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"P0005 - ORP TEST Dev Team 4 Mateusz"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)

Comment: Try to wait for element to be clickable: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: i tried waits, i even put a simple time.sleep from python but it still cant find it

Comment: maybe it is inside a iframe/frame? You first need to switch to it. It is hard for us to help you debug, because we do not have the website itself.

Comment: it worked! didnt realise i need to switch to iframe. thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps in debuging NoSuchElementException:

- First wait for item to be present: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
- Check if the element is in an iFrame. You need to switch to the frame first: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

For more debugging steps and ideas read: [How to analyse 'Element not Found' exceptions when working with Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium)