# How to resolve NoSuchElementException in Selenium Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide

I've been working on a company project involving `Selenium`and I keep getting `NoSuchElementException` despite putting `xpath`, `cssSelector` and `linkText`. Below is my program.

**NewCard.java**

```
public class NewCard {
public static void createTopUpRequestNewCard(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement utilityTopUp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a")));
    utilityTopUp.click();
    WebElement createTopUpNewCard = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")));
    createTopUpNewCard.click();
}
}
```

**Error StackTrace**

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at AbtMainTestControl.AutomationTesting.newcard.NewCard.createTopUpRequestNewCard(NewCard.java:41)
    at AbtMainTestControl.AutomationTesting.test.AutoTest.createTopUpRequest(AutoTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:63)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'EZL-OA-JACQUELI', ip: '192.168.130.18', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.141, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\lukegoh\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58598}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 78c5d3b2ff7e0a99e3da6b4bba18815b
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 34 more
```

**HTML Code**

**Utility Top Up**

```
<a href="#" class="menu__link"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-inline--fa fa-user fa-w-14 menu__icon" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="user" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm89.6 32h-16.7c-22.2 10.2-46.9 16-72.9 16s-50.6-5.8-72.9-16h-16.7C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4z"></path></svg><!-- <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user menu__icon"></i> --> Utility Top Up <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-right fa-w-10 menu__arrow-icon" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="chevron-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M285.476 272.971L91.132 467.314c-9.373 9.373-24.569 9.373-33.941 0l-22.667-22.667c-9.357-9.357-9.375-24.522-.04-33.901L188.505 256 34.484 101.255c-9.335-9.379-9.317-24.544.04-33.901l22.667-22.667c9.373-9.373 24.569-9.373 33.941 0L285.475 239.03c9.373 9.372 9.373 24.568.001 33.941z"></path></svg><!-- <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-right menu__arrow-icon"></i> --></a>
```

**Screenshot of `Utility Top Up` locators**

[image]

**Create Top Up New Card**

```
<a href="#" class="context-menu__link"> create top up request (new card) </a>
```

**Screenshot of `Create Top Up New Card` locators**

[image]

The screenshots above are the locators of the 2 elements I'm interacting respectively. I used `Selenium IDE` to record my program. Nevertheless, despite trying all these locators, I keep getting the `NoSuchElementException`. May I know how to solve these recurring issues?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium

Comment: please add your html

Comment: what happens if you use presence of element instead of located by ?

Comment: @PDHide You mean replace VisibilityofElementLocated with PresenceofElementLocated? Still doesn't make a difference

Comment: The HTML code is confusing as it uses a navigation drawer

Comment: I've tried using Explicit Wait, Fluent Wait and Implicit Wait and still doesn't work. My website uses Vue.JS framework

Comment: So it means the eelement is not present the page , your locator might be wrong or it might be a shadow element or inside iframe

Comment: element is present. And it's not in the iframe as the html code doesn't contain <iframe> tag.

Comment: We cannot help with just a small part of the HTML/DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

**use:**

```
//*[text()[contains(.,"Utility Top Up")]]
```

**use wait :**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated​(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,"Utility Top Up")]]")));
```

The text is inside anchor tag but there is a  tag in between text so , first get text contents using text() and check for utility Top in all the retrieved text content.

**Old**

If you are not getting element not found error after changing  VisibilityofElementLocated with PresenceofElementLocated , then it means selenium is not able to identify the element . Unless you provide the html it is hard to answer . THe only thing to recommend is :

1. **Your locator might be wrong** , verify if locator is correct by using dev tool ( Inpect element)
2. **Element might be inside iframe** , if so you should switch to frame first before you can find or interact with those elements
3. **Element might be a shadow element** , you should use javascript
   shadowRoot and queryselector scripts to find such shadow root elements.

Comment: I have included HTML Images so it would be neater

Comment: I have included HTML Code

Comment: @TechGeek49 for each elementent are you getting no element found ? utilityTopUp or createTopUpNewCard

Comment: In particular utilityTopUp. If that doesn't work, then createTopUpNewCard navigation doesn't work as well

Comment: since createTopUp is a subsection of UtilityTopUp navigation menu

Comment: I get NoSuchElementException and Unable to locate element

Comment: for the 1st one

Comment: @TechGeek49 use the xpath locator `//*[text()[contains(.,"Utility Top Up")]]` updated the answer

Comment: Still doesn't work. My website uses Vue.js framework on top of it

Comment: @TechGeek49 use webdriver wiat with it

Comment: You mean implicit wait? I have already added that but to no avail. I just can't seem to get past this and already informed my DEV team about this. kinda sucks how they programmed it imho

Comment: @TechGeek for the html which you have given , the locator works. You can verify that but pasting your html to an html file and using that locator

Comment: Yep, the locator works. But when I run I still get the same exception. On top of that, how do I extract the html code from a website? I only select specific web elements I interact with.

Comment: Can you help me out. I tried using MS Edge and Chrome but nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1):

You have twice the same selector: By.xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a")

Are you sure the second time the selector is exact the same? In my experience new elements that are created after a click have a different selector.

I would try a more simple selector like: `By.partialLinkText("Utility Top Up")`

If you want a better answer I need the following info:

- HTML/DOM sources of the part you are interacting with
- Is it the first wait or the second that cannot find the element

Comment: 1st wait I couldn't find it

Comment: Maybe it is in a frame? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium

Comment: It's not in a frame. Just checked

Comment: I have included HTML images for the portion I'm dealing with

Comment: Why not use a selector like: By.partialLinkText("Utility Top Up")

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. Always getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

try using Actions class :

Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(utilityTopUp).bulid().perform();
action.moveToElement(utilityTopUp).click().build().perform();

Comment: This doesn't even work